# Describe the centralizer

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, permutations, symmetric-groups

Exercise from Artin's Algebra.

> Describe the centralizer $Z (\sigma) $ of the permutation $\sigma = (153)(246)$  in the symmetric group $S_{7} $, and compute the orders of $Z (\sigma) $ and of $C (\sigma)$.

My progress:

Since $P= (1/\sqrt {2}) \begin {pmatrix} 1 & i \\ 1 & -i \end {pmatrix}$

has the property that $PAP^{*}$ is diagonal, and $PP^{*}=I $. For this sort of problem I think I am suppose to find a basis for eigenvalues vectors for A and normalize them so they give a unitary change of basis matrix. How would this be done?

Comment: One thing you can say is that it contains the subgroup generated by $(1,5,3)$ and $(2,4,6)$. It also contains the triple transposition $(1,3)(4,5)(3,6)$ which swaps the two 3-cycles as a result of conjugating your $\sigma$. What is $C(\sigma)$? And how did you get that matrix $P$, and how are you thinking of representing permutations as matrices?

Comment: I don't think it is helpful to bring matrices into this. Just do the calculation directly in $S_7$.  But I am confused by your notation. $C(\sigma)$ usually denotes the centralizer of $\sigma$ but you are using $Z(\sigma)$ for that, so what is your definition of $C(\sigma)$?

Comment: @DerekHolt, this question is from Artin's Algebra, and there he uses $C(\sigma)$ for conjugacy class of $\sigma$.